# Listing Graduate Assistantships on Resume

Tags: resume, work-experience

I'm working on my resume post graduate school (master's) and am having trouble deciding how to list assistantships. While in school I was a GRA under two different grants which funded entities withing the university(doing very different things) and a TA for on semester. I'm planning on listing these under work experience but should they each be listed as a unique experience (option 1) or should all the positions be listed as one entry (option 2). The obvious pros/cons are option 1 allows me to showcase a larger diversity of experiences and skills but takes up quite a bit of space option 2 is the opposite. Below is an example

Option 1

**Entity XYZ**

*Research Assistant*

- Description

**Entity ABC**

*Research Assistant*

- Description

**Department MNO**

*Teaching Assistant*

- Description

Option 2

**University of XYZ**

*Reasearch/Teaching Assistant*

- Description including various positions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as it doesn't bloat your resume past your target size (for most undergrad or masters students that's 1 page) and you're not duplicating information, go for the long form. In a few years you may find that all that work can be condensed in favor of professional experience, but for now, you're right to expound on what you've been doing.